# regular expression :inserting * make it computable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression as

ysin(yx)

i need to insert * as `y*sin(y*x)`

suppose my equation is yxsin(y) i need to get output as `y*x*sin(y)`
i tried with this code

```
function addStars(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\))([A-Za-z])/g,function(str, gr1, gr2) { return gr1 + "*" + gr2 }).replace(/x([A-Za-wy-z])/g,function(str, gr1) { return "x*" + gr1 });
}
var t=addStars("ysin(yx)");
alert(t);
```

what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using regular back-references in this case since you are not analyzing or manipulating the capture groups. The problem is that you are trying to match some letter after a `)` with `/(\))([A-Za-z])/g` - and you do not have any text after `)` in your example string `ysin(yx)`.

Here is a possible fix where I combined the `x` and `y` into a character class and set a capture group to be able to restore them in the result:

```js
function addStars(str) {
       return str.replace(/([xy])([A-Za-xz])/g,"$1*$2");
//                         |    |                ^
//                         ----------------------|
}
var t=addStars("ysin(yx)");
document.write(t + "<br/>");
var t=addStars("yxsin(y)");
document.write(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've generalized the approch using a function list as an anchor and splitting the variables list. The regex is case insensitive and accepts any letter `[a-z]` as variables prior and as arguments of the function. The trigonometric function list is `(asin|acos|atan|sin|cos|tan)` (can be expanded as well, only remember to put the longest function names first!).

Check if can be useful:

```js
function addStars(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z]*?)(asin|acos|atan|sin|cos|tan)\(([^\)]*)\)/i, function(str, vars, funcName, args) { 
        return vars.split('').join('*') + '*' + funcName + '(' + args.split('').join('*')+')';});
}

var t=addStars("ysin(yx)");
document.write(t + "<br/>");
var t=addStars("yxsin(y)");
document.write(t + "<br/>");
var t=addStars("ycos(abyxz)");
document.write(t + "<br/>");
var t=addStars("yxatan(yxz)");
document.write(t + "<br/>");
```